# How to use \texttt with CMU Typewriter Text in XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

The following example won't compile

```
\documentclass[xetex,sans,mathserif]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hello, world! \texttt{Hello, world!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

, whining that

```
** WARNING ** Obsolete four arguments of "endchar" will be used for Type 1 "seac" operator.
** ERROR ** This font using the "seac" command for accented characters...
```

It's perfectly OK to use `\setmonofont{Courier New}` though. So how do I use `CMU Typewriter Text` here?

Comment: I don't get such warning and error (but **beamer** tells something about options `sans` and `mathserif`); `otfinfo -i` tells that `cmuntt.otf` is version 0.7.0

Comment: I don't get these warnings either. I'm running MacTeX2011, and `otfinfo -i` on both `cmunss.otf` and `cmuntt.otf` reports versions of 0.6.3 and 0.6.3a, respectively. By the way, my version of `beamer` issues a warning that both the `sans` and `mathserif` options are obsolete.

Comment: run it with `lualatex` instaed of `xelatex` then it should work

Comment: I'm running MikTeX 2.9 and I don't really know how to find out OpenType font version under W7.

Comment: I've hit the same problem, but I can't use LuaTeX, as I need XeTeX's `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate` feature. Is there some other workaround? If this is a bug in the font files, who should it be reported to? The packager, or the cm-unicode project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Herbert! Running `lualatex` instead of `xelatex` worked like a charm! One must also replace `xetex` with `luatex` like `\documentclass[luatex]{beamer}`.

Comment: I suppose that you do not need that option, it can be detected by the system